# Kubernetes nginx-ingress: SSL wrong version number error

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to use nginx-ingress to create secure connection but i'm getting this error:
[image]

I'm using helm chart stable/nginx-ingress version 1.34.2.

I've been searching for this kind of error, I've already config ssl-ciphers and ssl-protocols, add more ciphers suite in order to have more common ciphers between client and server. But i'm still getting this error.

The service i'm trying to build following this flow:

[image]

Hope some one can solve this out, or having any suggestion for my problem.

Comment: Please provide more information about your issue as it lacks details. What have you done to get to this issue? What exactly are you trying to achieve? Additionally please provide `YAML` definitions of services and deployments.

Comment: What kind of certificate are you using? If self-signed, what encryption algorithm did you use?

Comment: @PoweredByOrange Thanks for your help. I'm using Lest Encrypt certificate. About the encryption algorithm, I don't know what encryption algorithm was used. All i know about the encryption is the cipher suite and the protocol of nginx. Does this error relate to the certificate?

Comment: @DawidKruk Thanks for your help. I installed nginx-ingress from this helm chart: github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress. All the configuration are default but externalIP was the cluster master IP. I also try to config the ssl-ciphers with more ciphers suite, and add TLSv1.3 to the ssl-protocols in controller.config (of the values.yaml). But the result still remain the same. The service i'm trying to build that follow the flow that i've updated above.